# MULTIPLE REPLACE IN ONE QUERY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some car model and I want them to replace with other random number.

```
KMAL
UT
NC
WI
KMMA
KMKS
MA
MI
KMNJ
KMAR
TN
NH
AK
OK
KMWA
KMNY
KMMI
KY
```

I want these to be replaced with some other random name. I can either run the below query each time to replace, but it is time consuming.

```
update 
  table
set column=REPLACE(column, 'KMAL', 'LAMK')
```

Any other way I can do it in one go.

Comment: Set a where condition to filter the model you want

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830191/t-sql-using-a-case-in-an-update-statement-to-update-certain-columns-depending-o

Answer (score 1):

You could nest the replace function

`update table set column=REPLACE(REPLACE(column, 'KMAR', 'RAMK'), 'KMAL', 'LAMK')`