# How to update in SQL based on different where clause

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have a table which has a structure as:

```
ID  DBInstance  DBName  Tag
1  | INS1     | master | NULL
2  | INS1     | tempdb | NULL
4  | INS2     | master | NULL
5  | INS2     | tempdb | NULL
```

I want to update the tag in this table as based on the condition as:
1) Update tag as "a" only for DBInstance as "INS1" and DBName as "master"
2) Update tag as "b" only for DBInstance as "INS2" and DBName as "tempdb".

And I want to update both of these two only in a single statement, not in two different update queries. How can I do so?
A query somewhat like this:

```
UPDATE tbl_test 
SET tag = 'a' where DBInstance in ('INS1') and DBName IN ('master'), 
tag = 'b' where DBInstance in ('INS2') and DBName IN ('tempdb')
```

But obviously, this query is wrong, so how can I do so?

Comment: possible duplicate of [T-SQL: Using a CASE in an UPDATE statement to update certain columns depending on a condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830191/t-sql-using-a-case-in-an-update-statement-to-update-certain-columns-depending-o)

Comment: @Tony is right, just use CASE statement, like `set tag CASE WHEN .....END`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `case when then` like this:

```
UPDATE tbl_test 
SET tag = case 
            when DBInstance = 'INS1' and DBName = 'master'
              then 'a'
            when DBInstance = 'INS2' and DBName = 'tempdb'
              then 'b'
            else NULL -- or may be tag, or default value which you want.
          end
```

Comment: @RahulTripathi - yes, I deleted my comment as I realised they were already null... but I thought I would mention it anyway, just in case anybody deleted values without realising