# UPDATE with WITH and CASE - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to change the values of a column to be a title constructed from info from two other tables, however I'm running into trouble getting the data in. I currently want to execute this query on all entries to the table. I'm getting a syntax error on CASE and I can't figure out why.

```
UPDATE campaigns AS cmp
    SET name = (
        WITH ptn AS (SELECT first_name, last_name FROM politicians WHERE id = cmp.politician_id),
            rc AS (SELECT office FROM races WHERE id = cmp.race_id)

        CASE
            WHEN rc.office IS NULL OR rc.office = '' THEN ptn.first_name || ' ' || ptn.last_name
            ELSE ptn.first_name || ' ' || ptn.last_name || ' for ' || rc.office
        END
    )
```

This is PostGres 9.4. Here's the error I'm getting

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "case"
LINE 5:   case
          ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "case"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 189
```

Comment: Added the error to the post

Comment: Please edit into your question. Also your exact postgresql version tag. Please read about asking questions in the help center.

Comment: I think the CTE's have to exist in front of the update statement.  Not in the middle as you have them.

Comment: @xQbert I just tried your suggestion, unfortunately it didn't work. I found this suggesting that my syntax might work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830191/t-sql-using-a-case-in-an-update-statement-to-update-certain-columns-depending-o

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The syntax error occurs because your co-related subquery isn't valid. You need to have some `select` statement after the two common table expressions:

The basic structure of a common table expression is this:

```
with ptn as (...),
  rc as (...)
select --<< you are missing this select here
```

But I think the whole thing can be written shorter and more efficiently (if I'm not mistaken)

```
UPDATE campaigns AS cmp
    SET name = CASE
                 WHEN rc.office IS NULL OR rc.office = '' THEN ptn.first_name || ' ' || ptn.last_name
                ELSE ptn.first_name || ' ' || ptn.last_name || ' for ' || rc.office
              END
from politicians ptn, races rc 
where ptn.id = cmp.politician_id
  and rc.id = cmp.race_id
```

Answer (score 22):

I would be inclined to do this with `from` clause:

```
UPDATE campaigns AS cmp
    SET name = (CASE WHEN rc.office IS NULL OR rc.office = ''
                     THEN ptn.first_name || ' ' || ptn.last_name
                     ELSE ptn.first_name || ' ' || ptn.last_name || ' for ' || rc.office
                END)
    FROM politicians ptn, races rc
    WHERE ptn.id = cmp.politician_id and rc.id = cmp.race_id ;
```